# The definition of Galois connection

Tags: order-theory

The definition about Galois connection at [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois_connection) is that

> Let $(A, \leq)$ and $(B, \leq)$ be two partially ordered sets. A monotone Galois connection between these posets consists of two monotone functions: $F\colon A \rightarrow B$ and $G\colon B \rightarrow A$, such that for all $a$ in $A$ and $b$ in $B$, we have
> $$F(a) \leq b~\text{if and only if}~ a \leq G(b).$$

The definition about Galois connection at [nlab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Galois+connection) is that

> Given posets $A$ and $B$, a Galois connection between $A$ and $B$ is a pair of order-reversing functions $f\colon{A}\rightarrow{B}$ and $g\colon{B}\rightarrow{A}$ such that $a \leq g(f(a))$ and $b \leq f(g(b))$ for all $a \in A$, $b \in B$.

I think they are equivalent, so i start proof it, but there is problem: suppose $(f,g)$ is a galois connection statisfies nlab definition, then i assume $a \leq g(b)$ and want to proof $f(a) \leq b$. we have $f(a) \leq f(g(b))$, but nlab's definition told us $b \leq f(g(b))$, so i can't go on.

i think the $b \leq f(g(b))$ should be changed to $f(g(b)) \leq b$. i dont know its right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained in their very first paragraph, the definition on nLab refers to an **antitone** Galois connection, not **monotone** as on Wikipedia. So all inequalities on the “B” side are reversed.

Comment: My mistakes! i should notice that "order-reversing" in definition at nLab, thank u!